# Umbraco 7 How to hide Redirect Url Management for Writer role

Tags: url-rewriting, umbraco

I have a Umbraco 7 website. I created a user in writer role for my editors. When I log in to umbraco admin with the new user I see "Redirect Url Management". I don't want my editors to see this module as they will get confused (and I am affraid that they will broke something). Does anyone know how to hide this for this specific role or user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit these settings in `/Config/Dashboard.config` file.

Look for the section called `RedirectUrlManagement`. You can either remove the section completely or edit the `areas` section to set the access level. Like for devs:

```
<areas>
    <area>developer</area>
</areas>
```